# How can we push to errorPage if the server send a 404 message in react hooks page

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How can we push to `/errorPage` if the server send a 404 message in react hooks page. I am checking if the token is valid in the server side and in the else condition send a `404` message, in that case I would like to display an errorPage. Is that a good approach, please advise !

/* This service is used to submit a nomination */
`server.js`

```
app.post('/service/nominateperson', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const nomineeName = req.body.nomineename;
    const nomineeEmail = req.body.email;
    const description = req.body.description;
    const nominatedBy = req.body.nominatedby;
    var data = {nomineename:nomineeName, email:nomineeEmail, description:description, nominatedby:nominatedBy};
    console.log("Server side display nominations :" + data);
    const checkTokenData = await LinkTokenModel.findAll({ attributes: ['token','expiredAt']});
    const expiryDate = checkTokenData[0].expiredAt;
    const formattedExpiryDate = moment(expiryDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
    const tokenData = checkTokenData[0].token;
    var now = moment();
    var currentDate = moment(now).format('YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm');
    if(currentDate < formattedExpiryDate ){
      const nominationData = await NominationModel.create(data);
      res.status(200).json({message: "Nomination send successfully !"});
    } else {
      res.status(404).json({ fail:true});
    }
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).json({ fail: e.message });
  }
});
```

`nominate.js`

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
 const history = useHistory();

    const onSubmit = () => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const res = await Axios.post('http://localhost:8000/service/nominateperson', formRegister);
                if (res.data) {
                    console.log("Link token created:" + res.data);
                    const successMessage = res.data.message;
                    setHelperText(successMessage);
                } else {
                    history.push('/errorPage');
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
        fetchData();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `catch(e)` part of the code, use something like `history.push('404')` to redirect browser.

If there is a page for the route, it will be shown

Comment: Appreciate your help, this is working. May I ask if we can put that in else condition in client side ? is that possible ?

Comment: @soccerway  Sure, I was meaning client side in the first place. Which seems to be ```nominate.js``` in your case